# WPF C# datagrid object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

I'm getting really tire of this error. What object,what reference, what...Sigh... Anyway, what I'm doing here is filling a data grid with data from the database. I'm looking for my record... regardless of whether or not I actually select an item, when I press the search button again (maybe to refine the search params), I get the error about "object reference not set to an instance of an object". It keeps crapping out on the "Pnum" line in the code below:

```
private void DgPatSrch_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var id = ((DataRowView)DgPatSrch.SelectedItem).Row["Pnum"].ToString();
        var name = ((DataRowView)DgPatSrch.SelectedItem).Row["Pname"].ToString();
        var dob = ((DataRowView)DgPatSrch.SelectedItem).Row["Dob"].ToString();
        TbPatIdReadOnly.Text = id;
        TbPatNameReadOnly.Text = name;
        TbDobReadOnly.Text = dob;

    }
```

So, how would I fill a data grid, not like what I filled it with, pass new params, and repopulate it? Everything seems to work EXCEPT the repopulate. It almost seems like I need to reinitialize the data grid or clear or refresh... but none of those have worked... Help please!!!

Comment: My bad. What is the ItemsSource of the datagrid? Should have asked that first. I may need to edit my answer after rereading your post

Comment: Please debug the problem deeply enough that you can get farther than asking about the `NullReferenceException` itself. You should not even need to mention the exception; your debugging should take you to the root cause, and you should ask a question about _that_. Please also make sure you provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so we can avoid people posting guesses as answers. Sometimes the guesses will be right, but too often they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `SelectedItem` will become `null` when you repopulate the grid.

You will want to first extract the selected item, cast it to the correct type as `SelectedItem` property returns an `object` and then use the cast object as needed. This is provided it is not `null`

```
private void DgPatSrch_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var selectedItem = DgPatSrch.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if(selectedItem != null) {
        var id = selectedItem.Row["Pnum"].ToString();
        var name = selectedItem.Row["Pname"].ToString();
        var dob = selectedItem.Row["Dob"].ToString();
        TbPatIdReadOnly.Text = id;
        TbPatNameReadOnly.Text = name;
        TbDobReadOnly.Text = dob;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect response.Thank you.This was exactly what I needed.